# gnuplot autotitle columnheader with whitespaces

Tags: whitespace, gnuplot, space, legend, columnheader

How can I create a legend with whitespaces in the column header with autotitle? E.g. the first two lines of the data file:

```
T "x high" "x low"
0.1 3.14 0.0554
```

The legend should be:

```
T
x high
x low
```

Unfortunately gnuplot interprets it like this:

```
T
x
high
```

The quotes are simply ignored and the second column header is split into two. I couldn't find any information about this on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, which gnuplot version 4.6 the following works:

```
set key autotitle columnheader
plot 'file.dat' using 1:2 , '' using 1:3
```

and gives the legend

```
x high
x low
```

There is no problem with quoting.

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. There was a line in my gnuplot script: set datafile separator " ". I don't remember why I've put it in there but without that command I get whitespaces in my titles as well.